# What are the -interactive- alternatives to IFrames

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Well met!

I am working on a project similar to the Windows 8 tile-interface, only for Websites.

The idea is that, when a tile is clicked, it grows to fill the site (leaving a menu-bar on the top free) and the user can reguarly browse the loaded site. When he clicks a button on the menu-bar, the tile grows back.

My approach was to use IFrames. But those can be disabled through a HTTP-option by the visited site, or by using some javascript to test window toplevel.

Therefore I need some kind of alternative to IFrames. The best thing I was able to find was the JQuery `.load(url)`, which only displays the content of the site, not making it regulary useable. It was very slow in my tests, too.

Is there something I can use, or do I have to drop the idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading resources from different origins is very limited on the client side. Your best bet is probably a proxy on the server side (which isn't a perfect solution as it's used by scammers, read about it carefully) - I remember this [iPad simulator](http://alexw.me/ipad2/) has a fake Mobile Safari browser which uses [php simple proxy](https://github.com/cowboy/php-simple-proxy/).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. At first, it looked very promising, but after a little playing around with it I had to notice that a lot of sites are not useable (try googleing something) or have interactive parts missing, like log-in forms.

Comment: Right. As much as we'd love to build browsers-in-browsers, no website likes the thought of users logging in or submitting any sensitive data to a third party proxy.

Comment: So basicly, a full browser-in-browser functionality can not be achived in this way. In that case, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

**Using Client Side Technology ...**
jQuery's .load() will fetch the resource using AJAX and is constrained by the same-domain origin policy (security sandbox) that is inherent to the XMLHttpRequest object.

an iFrame will load the resource but as you pointed out it has drawbacks.

**Using Server Side Technology ...**
if you have only a few websites in the tiles that will need to be opened, you could preload them using a server side technology (php, jsp, asp) and hide them in a container object (like a div element) and then programmatically show them when the user activates the tile though a hover or click event.

Using java for example, you could use the java.net library to open a string buffer, read and save the contents of the website, and then add the variable to the servlet response.  Using JSTL you would output the variable from the response object.